# More buffering when ffmpeg saving rtsp to mkv file

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I have a GSM connection to my cameras. When I playback stream directly from cameras everythink is OK, but if I save the same stream to file I have 80% of broken frame like this:
[image: broken frame]

My ffmpeg params:

```
  ffmpeg -i rtsp://login:pass@IP:554/Streaming/Channels/102?transportmode=unicast&profile=Profile_2'\
   -hide_banner -y\
   -loglevel error\
   -rtsp_transport tcp\
   -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1\
   -acodec copy\
   -vcodec copy\
   -f segment\
   -segment_time 900\
   -segment_format mkv\
   -segment_atclocktime 1\
   -strftime 1\
   -reset_timestamps 1\
   $BASEDIRECTORY/$YEAR/$MONTH/$DAY/%d_%H-%M.mp4
```

Maybe I need more buffering or something like this?
Please help.

Comment: Try adding `-rtbufsize 300M` before the `-i`

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: I get warns ins logs:
```[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] max delay reached. need to consume packetA speed=1.11x            
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] RTP: missed 28 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] max delay reached. need to consume packetA speed=1.11x    
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] RTP: missed 33 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] max delay reached. need to consume packetA speed= 1.1x    
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] RTP: missed 13 packets
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x5582872700] RTP: missed 3 packets```

Comment: and such errors:
```[h264 @ 0x55960ff7d0] left block unavailable for requested intra4x4 mode -1
[h264 @ 0x55960ff7d0] error while decoding MB 0 14, bytestream 3150
[h264 @ 0x55960ff7d0] concealing 409 DC, 409 AC, 409 MV errors in I frame
```

Comment: and this:
```[segment @ 0x5596235560] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
[segment @ 0x5596235560] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 0, current: 0; changing to 1. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
```

Comment: Maybe your disk is too slow for storing the data in realtime... are you using an HDD or SSD? What is the video bitrate sent by the camera? For testing try using simpler command - keep `-acodec copy` and `-vcodec copy`, but remove the other arguments. Note that using `-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1` is usually not recommended. Using `-segment_format mkv` with `.mp4` file extension is also a problem (unrelated to the issue). I recommend you to search the error messages in Google, I don't think I can help you...

Comment: I solved my issue. `-rtsp_transport tcp` must be before `-i`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue. `-rtsp_transport tcp` must be before `-i`.